# interior, boundary, closure of some sets in plane

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

$\newcommand{\intr}{\operatorname{int}}$

For the following sets $E ⊆ \mathbb{R}^2 $, I need to find $E'$ , $\overline E$, $\intr(E)$ and $∂E$.

(a) $E = \{(x, y) : 1 < x^2 + y ^2 ≤ 4\}$,

(b) $E = \{(x, y) : x > 0, xy = 1\}$,

(c) $E = \{(x, y) : x, y ∈ Q\}$,

(d) $E = \{(x, y) : y = 0\}$,

(e) $E = \{(x, y) : x ∈ Q\}$,

(f) $E = \{(x, y) : x^2 + y^2\text{ is rational}\}$,

(g) $E = \{(x, y) : 1/x\text{ is an integer}\}$,

(h) $E = \{(x, y) : x^2 + y^ 2 < 1,\text{ and }y < 0\}$.

for (a), $E'=\{(x,y): 1\le x^2+y^2\le 4\}=\overline E, \intr E=\{(x,y): 1< x^2+y^2< 4\}$ It has two boundary $x^2+y^2=4,\& x^2+y^2=1$

for $(b)$ it is a one part of hyperbola in firsy quadrant, it has interior empty, limit points are itself, boundaryless, clousure is itself,

$(c)$ is a dense set interior is empty and clousure is whole $\mathbb{R}^2$ I have no idea about the boundary of this one.

(d) it is just $X$ axis, same as $(b)$,

$e$ is dense so same as $c$,

$f,g$ I have no idea,

$h$ is open set it is actually open lower semidisk I know about interior closure and boundary.

advanced Thank you for pointing my mistakes and discussion.

Comment: 1) Note $\partial E = \bar E - int(E)$. 2) Hint for (e): it is a bunch of vertical lines parallel to $y$-axis.  3) Hint for (f): it's a bunch of circles, with what radius?  4) Hint for (g): it is again a bunch of vertical lines parallel to $y$-axis, and think about $\frac{1}{x} = 1, 2, 3, \cdots$ so where are these vertical lines?

Comment: For part (f), the set is the union of all circles about the origin with rational radius. You should be able to show that this is dense, with empty interior. For part (g), you're looking at the set of all vertical lines of the form $x=\frac1n,$ where $n$ is a non-zero integer.

Comment: @CameronBuie & Secret Math, Thank you :)

Comment: Oops! Mistake for part (f). The set **contains** all circles about the origin of rational radius. It also contains (for example) the circle about the origin of radius $\sqrt2$. It's still dense with empty interior, though.